# USB Support in Qemu User Mode Emulation

Tags: usb, raspberry-pi, raspbian, qemu

I have a CLI program compiled for x86_64 for which I have no source code (a firmware programming utility).  I would like to run this on a Raspberry Pi.

The program runs fine using Qemu user mode emulation, but no USB devices are detected.  Is it possible to use this mode of operation with USB devices?  If so, what configuration am I missing?

To set up the emulation, I have followed [Transparently running binaries from any architecture in Linux with QEMU and binfmt_misc](https://ownyourbits.com/2018/06/13/transparently-running-binaries-from-any-architecture-in-linux-with-qemu-and-binfmt_misc/), except in the reverse direction (x86_64 on ARM rather than ARM on x86_64) and, for now, I am not using a separate chroot, just a folder containing the x86_64 libraries I need.

The USB device I am using works fine with other (native) software on the Raspberry Pi.

Some more specific details in case they are useful:

- Raspberry Pi 1B+
- Connecting to a STM32 Nucleo programmer
- Attempting to run `STM32_Programmer_CLI` or, for testing, `lsusb`
- OS: Raspbian Buster

Environment setup:

```
$ sudo apt-get install qemu-user
$ ls -R ~/x86_64
x86_64:
lib
lib64
libc.so.6
libdl.so.2
libgcc_s.so.1
libglib-2.0.so.0
libgthread-2.0.so.0
libm.so.6
libpcre.so.1
libpthread.so.0
libstdc++.so.6
libudev.so.1
libusb-1.0.so.0
libz.so.1

x86_64/lib64:
ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/pi/x86_64/ QEMU_LD_PREFIX=/home/pi/x86_64/ ./lsusb
# Would expect to see a listing of USB devices here, but there is no output.
```

PS: I am aware of other ways to use this programmer with a native utility (st-link, openocd), but I have had different issues there.